# Batch file to store password to clipboard and clear after 60 second

Tags: batch

I am trying to create a batch file that will store a password onto the clipboard and then start a hidden timer that will erase the clipboard after 60 seconds.

I have created 2 files to do this but I want to make it cleaner with 1 file.

When I tried to make this in 1 file it left the cmd window open which showed the password for 60 seconds before it cleared the clipboard which doesn't work for me since I don't want anyone who isnt authorized to see the password.

my first file is

```
echo|set /p=MyPassWord|clip
echo.
exit
```

my second file is

```
echo|<nul set /p="" | clip
dir >nul | clip 
cd %cd% | clip
pushd %cd% | clip
cd >nul | clip
echo.
exit
```

Any help would be greatly appreciatedand thanks in advance

Comment: I presume this is so you can copy it to whatever website or application it's for.  Why not  just use a password manager ?

Comment: Batch is very limited, but this can easily be accomplished with powershell as it has native clipboard monitoring support etc.

Comment: Looks like XY Problem to me ! (1) During the 60 seconds, Pasting somewhere else (say into text file) will reveal the PassWord (2) When ClipBoard managers (or ClipBoard monitors) are running, the N newest ClipBoard Contents will be available (3) In case the ClipBoard has Critical Data to be used in the application after login, then that will be temporarily lost when  PassWord is loaded into ClipBoard (4) We have to know what OP is trying to achieve before giving a Solution.

Comment: This is to paste it into an area that you enter the password which anything in that field shows up as *** so they cannot see it.  The machine is locked up kind of tight so I am not sure if a password manager can be installed and even if it can since this field is opened up from within a already running program I am not sure if a password manager would recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your own script, the following will make it work, clear the screen and wait for 60 seconds before executing the second part.

```
@echo off

echo|set /p=MyPassWord|clip
echo.

cls
ping localhost -n 60 >nul

echo|<nul set /p="" | clip
dir >nul | clip 
cd %cd% | clip
pushd %cd% | clip
cd >nul | clip
echo.
exit
```

Comment: Thanks and this does work well for what I need.  Is there a way to minimize the cmd prompt to the taskbar as well before it closes so the techs dont see it and think they have to click the x to close it out?

Comment: figured it out by adding `if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You don't need to port your 2 bats to 1 bat
**2.** Just create a shortcut with the line below
**3.** Configure the shortcut options so that it runs minimized...
**4.** The password will be on your clipboard for the time defined in `pathping`

**Note:** For 60 seconds use `-p 60000` in the `pathping` command

```bath
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /q /v /r "echo\[Your-Password-Here]|clip && start /b "" cmd.exe /q /r "pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 60000 >nul & cd.|clip""
```

---